# How to run jFileChooser in console-application? Is it possible?

Tags: java, console-application, jfilechooser, directory-browsing

I tried to do this with this piece of code:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int retval = JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION;
chooser.setFileSelectionMode( JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
retval = chooser.showDialog(null, "Select");
```

But it didn't work. Console just waited for input...

Comment: Interesting, it should normally work ok...

Comment: Wich JDK version are you using?

Comment: @Jhurtado jdk1.6.0_26 When I run exported.jar and run in console: java exported.jar I get NoClassDefFoundError...

Comment: I don't think its a problem with your code, I created a same class with main and your code and it worked perfectly. Can you check your jar and the manifest file?

Comment: I've got this in manifest: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: projekt.Main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run it as `java -jar exported.jar`